# Recommendations on handling object status fields in rails apps: store versus calculate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, data-modeling

I have a rails app that tracks membership cardholders, and needs to report on a cardholder's status.  The status is defined - by business rule - as being either "in good standing," "in arrears," or "canceled," depending on whether the cardholder's most recent invoice has been paid.

Invoices are sent 30 days in advance, so a customer who has just been invoiced is still in good standing, one who is 20 days past the payment due date is in arrears, and a member who fails to pay his invoice more than 30 days after it is due would be canceled.

I'm looking for advice on whether it would be better to store the cardholder's current status as a field at the customer level (and deal with the potential update anomalies resulting from potential updates of invoice records without updating the corresponding cardholder's record), or whether it makes more sense to simply calculate the current cardholder status based on data in the database every time the status is requested (which could place a lot of load on the database and slow down the app).

Recommendations?  Or other ideas I haven't thought of?

One important constraint: while it's unlikely that anyone will modify the database directly, there's always that possibility, so I need to try to put some safeguards in place to prevent the various database records from becoming out of sync with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The storage of calculated data in your database is generally an optimisation. I would suggest that you calculate the value on every request and then monitor the performance of your application. If the fact that this data is not stored becomes an issue for you then is the time to refactor and store the value within the database.

Storing calculated values, particularly those that can affect multiple tables are generally a bad idea for the reasons that you have mentioned.

When/if you do refactor and store the value in the DB then you probably want a batch job that checks the value for data integrity on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to calculate the current cardholder status based on data in the database every time the status is requested.  That way you have no duplication of data, and therefore no potential problems with the duplicates becoming out of step.

If, and only if, your measurements show that this calculation is causing a significant slowdown, then you can think about caching the value.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had similar decision to take and I decided to store status as a field in database. This is because I wanted to reduce sql queries and it looks simpler. I choose to do it that way because I will very often need to get this status and calculating it is (at least in my case) a bit complicated.

Possible problem with it is that it get out of sync, so I added some `after_save` and `after_destroy` to child model, to keep it synchronized. And of course if somebody would modify database in different way, it would make some problems.

You can write simple rake task that will check all statuses and, if needed, correct them. You can run it in cron so you don't have to worry about it.